# Change table structure in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, excel-2016

Currently I've a table like below where I collect EMIs for all our borrowers.

```
+---------+-----------------+----------+-------------------+-----------------+----------+-------------------+------------+----------+-------------------+
|  Name   |            Vinesh Pardeshi                     |         Satyajit Chavan                        |   Varsha                                  |
+---------+-----------------+----------+-------------------+-----------------+----------+-------------------+------------+----------+-------------------+
| Country | India                                          | Europe                                         | Japan                                     |
|         |                 |          |                   |                 |          |                   |            |          |                   |
|         | Date            | Cashflow | Status of payment | Date            | Cashflow | Status of payment | Date       | Cashflow | Status of payment |
| EMI1    | 15-08-2017      | 5000     | Paid              | 15-08-2017      | 8400     | Unpaid            | 31-08-2017 | 40003    | Pending           |
| EMI2    | 15-09-2017      | 5000     | Pending           | 15-09-2017      | 7700     | Pending           | 30-09-2017 | 6441     | Pending           |
| EMI3    | 15-10-2017      | 5000     | Pending           | 15-10-2017      | 7700     | Pending           | 30-10-2017 | 6441     | Pending           |
| EMI4    | 15-11-2017      | 5000     | Pending           | 15-11-2017      | 7700     | Pending           | 30-11-2017 | 6441     | Pending           |
| EMI5    | 15-12-2017      | 5000     | Pending           | 15-12-2017      | 7700     | Pending           | 30-12-2017 | 6441     | Pending           |
| EMI6    | 15-01-2018      | 5000     | Pending           | 15-01-2018      | 7700     | Pending           | 30-01-2018 | 6441     | Pending           |
| EMI7    | 15-02-2018      | 5000     | Pending           | 15-02-2018      | 7700     | Pending           | 28-02-2018 | 6441     | Pending           |
| EMI8    |                 |          |                   | 15-03-2018      | 7700     | Pending           | 28-03-2018 | 6441     | Pending           |
| EMI9    |                 |          |                   | 15-04-2018      | 7700     | Pending           | 28-04-2018 | 6441     | Pending           |
| EMI10   |                 |          |                   |                 |          |                   | 28-05-2018 | 6441     | Pending           |
| EMI11   |                 |          |                   |                 |          |                   | 28-06-2018 | 6441     | Pending           |
+---------+-----------------+----------+-------------------+-----------------+----------+-------------------+------------+----------+-------------------+
```

I have data for more than 200 clients. As new clients gets acquired three new columns gets added at the end of the table. So the solution needs to be dynamic to cover any added new columns.

Now I wanted to know how much EMIs are pending/paid for each country and what is total value for those EMIs pending or paid.

For that I want to create a table something like this below

```
+-----------------+---------+------------+----------+-------------------+
|      Name       | Country |    Date    | Cashflow | Status of payment |
+-----------------+---------+------------+----------+-------------------+
| Vinesh Pardeshi | India   | 15-08-2017 |     5000 | Paid              |
| Vinesh Pardeshi | India   | 15-09-2017 |     5000 | Pending           |
| Vinesh Pardeshi | India   | 15-10-2017 |     5000 | Pending           |
| Vinesh Pardeshi | India   | 15-11-2017 |     5000 | Pending           |
| Vinesh Pardeshi | India   | 15-12-2017 |     5000 | Pending           |
| Vinesh Pardeshi | India   | 15-01-2018 |     5000 | Pending           |
| Vinesh Pardeshi | India   | 15-02-2018 |     5000 | Pending           |
| Satyajit Chavan | Europe  | 15-08-2017 |     8400 | Unpaid            |
| Satyajit Chavan | Europe  | 15-09-2017 |     7700 | Pending           |
| Satyajit Chavan | Europe  | 15-10-2017 |     7700 | Pending           |
| Satyajit Chavan | Europe  | 15-11-2017 |     7700 | Pending           |
| Satyajit Chavan | Europe  | 15-12-2017 |     7700 | Pending           |
| Satyajit Chavan | Europe  | 15-01-2018 |     7700 | Pending           |
| Satyajit Chavan | Europe  | 15-02-2018 |     7700 | Pending           |
| Satyajit Chavan | Europe  | 15-03-2018 |     7700 | Pending           |
| Satyajit Chavan | Europe  | 15-04-2018 |     7700 | Pending           |
| Varsha          | Japan   | 31-08-2017 |    40003 | Pending           |
| Varsha          | Japan   | 30-09-2017 |     6441 | Pending           |
| Varsha          | Japan   | 30-10-2017 |     6441 | Pending           |
| Varsha          | Japan   | 30-11-2017 |     6441 | Pending           |
| Varsha          | Japan   | 30-12-2017 |     6441 | Pending           |
| Varsha          | Japan   | 30-01-2018 |     6441 | Pending           |
| Varsha          | Japan   | 28-02-2018 |     6441 | Pending           |
| Varsha          | Japan   | 28-03-2018 |     6441 | Pending           |
| Varsha          | Japan   | 28-04-2018 |     6441 | Pending           |
| Varsha          | Japan   | 28-05-2018 |     6441 | Pending           |
| Varsha          | Japan   | 28-06-2018 |     6441 | Pending           |
+-----------------+---------+------------+----------+-------------------+
```

So that I can pivot the data later on. Please guide me on how I can achieve that using excel. I am using Excel 2016.

Comment: Is the sole reason for your desire to have this new table format simply to be able to do this calculation for the EMI's per country? If so, I would say that a new table is not required and that a formula can probably be made to perform that calculation in the existing format. Admittedly, the calculation would be easier in this new format but I think it is still possible.

Comment: Actually like country I have more than 10 fields respective to each loan. And  I need to create that table to create charts based on those fields. But if a formula works telling how many EMIs are pending on my entire porfolio that would be helpful too.

Comment: Are you looking for a formula to generate the second table based on the first table?

Comment: Either way formula or power query or pivot table.. I just want to create that table.

Comment: I think using a formula would be too convoluted. May be possible with VBA or powerquery but neither of these are my expertise. I recommend adding these two tags to your post to attract people who are experts on these subjects.

Comment: This could (possibly) be done with [M / Power Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt211003.aspx). Yet, I'd lean more towards VBA as this table setup is anything but standard. Besides, there are so many posts on `UNPIVOT` using VBA that you shouldn't have any problems finding a suitable solution: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bexcel-vba%5d%20unpivot

Comment: It would really help if we can achieve this using either of the methods. @Ralph Can you please provide any solutions using powerquery or VBA. But the solution need to dynamic as new columns(loans) are added every week.

Comment: Yes I do know that. I was not asking for VBA code. However, having a good grip over power query I was seeking on how to resolve this, where the solution is dynamic. I know I can achieve this manually unpivoting every EMI table. But making it dynamic is what my biggest challenge

Comment: If there is a formula or Powerquery way to solve this situation. I know this falls under unpivoting table. But I have a dynamically increasing table having a different structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a table like this (I named mine Table1):

[image]

Load it as a source into Power Query (In Excel 2016: Data -> From Table).

It'll look like this in Power Query:

[image]

Click Transform -> Transpose, to flip the table 90 degrees.

It'll look like this:

[image]

Click Transform -> Use First Row as Headers.

It'll look like this:

[image]

Select *both* the Name and Country columns, then click Transform -> Fill -> Down.

It'll look like this:

[image]

Select the Name, Country, Column3 columns, and the untitled column (the one with Date, Cashflow, and Status of payment in it) then click Transform -> Unpivot Columns (drop-down arrow) -> Unpivot Other Columns:

[image]

It'll look like this:

[image]

Select the untitled column (the one with Date, Cashflow, and Status of payment in it) and click Transform -> Pivot Column. Fill out the pop-up window like this and click OK:

[image]

It'll look like this:

[image]

Select the Column3 and Attribute columns and click Home -> Remove Columns.

If there are any blanks in the Date column, select the filter drop-down button on the Date column and filter out any blanks by deselecting the checkbox by (blank) and clicking OK:

[image]

It'll look like this:

[image]

**Answer to question about adding info:**

Yes. This will accommodate additional info...added to the right of the existing source table *in Excel* (mine was Table1), as long as you maintain the same format. So if I add "Other Person" like this:

[image]

If you then select the source table *in Excel* (Table1) and click Data -> Refresh All, then switch to the newer tab that was created by Power Query when you first ran the query, you'll see it has been updated with the new info. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Wow. Great. I was looking for something like this. Can we make the initial table dynamic? As new columns are getting added for each new record and that table range needs to be changed

Comment: Yes. It will accommodate adding new records in the manner you've described...as 3 new columns to the right of the existing data. I added a little bit at the end of my answer, to discuss and show how that works. I also corrected a problem with the Unpivot Other Columns instruction (I had left out a column that you needed to select before clicking to unpivot). Lastly, I updated some of the screen clips.

Comment: One additional problem with the above is my data is that the data is not getting updated on the table. I have to update the data in a table, which means I'd have to maintain a table with same records. Effectively I am storing same data twice. Is there a way to use dynamic range in Power Query? Internet suggestions didn't help much

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly mean by "the data is not getting updated on the table."